# How to control the background color of the first slidify slide?

Tags: r, slidify

As a slidifiy newbee, I don't understand why the first slide has a pale green background and all the other slides have white backgrounds.

The example "Test for Slidify" at http://www.rpubs.com/ also shows this pale green first slide.

How can I control the background color of this first slidify slide?

Comment: Here's the pale green color on this example: http://bl.ocks.org/ramnathv/7155433    How is the color defined in the .cmd file?  How can it be changed?

Answer (score 19):

The css defining the title slide is contained in `libraries/frameworks/io2012/slidify.css`. Here is the part that controls the title slide. You can modify it and add it to your Rmd file directly to override default styles.

```
.title-slide {
  background-color: #CBE7A5; /* #EDE0CF; ; #CA9F9D*/
}

.title-slide hgroup > h1{
 font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica', sanserif; 
}

.title-slide hgroup > h1, 
.title-slide hgroup > h2 {
  color: #535E43 ;  /* ; #EF5150*/
}
```

To do this from within an `.Rmd` file, one would add the following after the `YAML` front matter section of `index.Rmd`. This applies a white background to the title slide:

```
---
title       : title slide bg change example
author      : Ramnath
...
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
knit        : slidify::knito2slides
---

<style>
.title-slide {
  background-color: #FFFFFF; /* #EDE0CF; ; #CA9F9D*/
}
</style>
```

Remember to re-run `slidify("index.Rmd")` to apply the change.

Comment: Ramnath, could it be possible to implement changing first slide colour and whole presentation font in Rmarkdown?

Comment: Yes. You can add the css directly to your Rmarkdown between `<style>` and `</style>` tags, and it would override the default css.

Comment: where does `<style>` and `</style>` go in the `.Rmd` file

Comment: ^I have the same question. I've placed it in every spot in my .rmd file and nothing changes...

Comment: @Ramnath I tried what you said using `<style>` tags and it worked just fine. I added this to your already helpful answer just to explicitly get at the comments inquiring. Hopefully that wasn't overstepping my bounds and feel free to edit/update at will! Just thought it would be helpful since folks were asking.